# A misunderstanding on the independence of orientation of line integrals?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I've found the following problem:

> Calculate the line integral of the first kind
>   $$\int_C (x+y)ds$$
>   Where $C$ is the contour of the triangle $ABO$ with the vertices at $A=(1,0),B=(0,1),C=(0,0)$.

In the previous presentation of the subject, it says that the line integral of the first kind is independent of the orientation. So, we compute first from $A$ to $B$ by acknowledging that this path is given by the line $y=1-x$ and in the solution, the author computes:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{2} dx$$

Doing this way, we get $\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{2} dx=\sqrt{2}$ but here we are computing the value from $B$ to $A$ and not from $A$ to $B$.  We should compute it as

$$\int_{1}^{0}\sqrt{2} dx$$

But doing this way, it would yield $-\sqrt{2}$ and our line integral should be independent of the path of integration. How come we get two different results? I may have understood something wrong.

Notice that I computed only the segment from $A$ to $B$ but looking at the solution, it doesn't seems the situation is going to change if I compute for the whole triangle.

Comment: Look at Examples $3$ and $4$ [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/LineIntegralsPtI.aspx)

Comment: When I parametrized the line segment with the two orientations, I got the same answer for each line integral.

Comment: @saulspatz Ah, I see. But it depends on that kind of parametrization, isn't it? When I used $y=1-x$, I ran into trouble.

Comment: @JG123 But what did you use? The parametrization suggested by saulspatz?

Comment: Right. Just use the ordinary parametrization of a line segment and you should be all set.

Comment: Note that the sign of $dx$ will change as well!

Comment: @erfink Why? It's not clear to me.

Comment: @BillyRubina Wall of text incoming, sit tight

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We're looking to compute the scalar line integral
$$\int_\mathcal{C_1} (x+y) ds$$
where $\mathcal{C_1}$ is the straight line segment from $A=(1,0)$ to $B=(0,1)$.

### Optimal Solution

In order to compute a line integral, we should parametrize our curve, say
$$\vec{r}(t) = \langle 1-t, t \rangle \quad 0 \leq t \leq 1.$$
Then $ds = \Vert \vec{r}'(t) \Vert dt= \sqrt{2}dt$ and so
\begin{align*}
\int_\mathcal{C_1} (x+y) ds &= \int_0^1 (1-t + t) \sqrt{2} dt \\
&= \int_0^1 \sqrt{2} dt \\
&= \sqrt{2}.
\end{align*}
Done. Note that our parametrization was from point $A$ (at $\vec{r}(0)$) to point $B$ (at $\vec{r}(1)$), with agrees with the standard orientation on the real number line (from 0 to 1).

### What about the reverse orientation?

Let's parametrize from $B$ to $A$ instead, say
$$\vec{r}(t) = \langle t, 1-t \rangle \quad 0 \leq t \leq 1.$$
As before, $ds = \Vert \vec{r}'(t) \Vert dt = \sqrt{2} dt$ and again we get \begin{align*}
\int_{\mathcal{C_1}} (x+y) ds &= \int_0^1 \sqrt{2} dt\\
& = \sqrt{2}.
\end{align*}

Notice that we get the same result because $ds$ *only cares about the magnitude* of $\vec{r}'(t)$, not the direction. This is precisely the difference between speed and velocity.

**Notice** that when I wanted to do this integral with the reverse orientation, I did **not** just swap the bounds of integration! I found a new parametrization **and** I chose bounds suitable for my parametrization.

### So what about the setup in the question?

Going through the entire parametrization with $\vec{r}(t)$ seems annoying; why not just use that $\overline{AB}$ is part of the curve given by $y=1-x$?

Sure, no problem. We still need to account for $ds$:
\begin{align*}
ds &= \sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2}\\
 &= \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 } ~dx \\
 &= \sqrt{1+ (-1)^2} ~dx \\
 &= \sqrt{2} ~dx. 
\end{align*}
All good. Let's set up our integral and go from $B$ to $A$. When $x=0$, $y=1$ and we're at point $B$ so $x=0$ is our lower limit. When $x=1$, $y=0$ and we're at point $A$ so $x=1$ is our upper limit. **Here's the key bit:** as $x$ goes from $0$ to $1$, it agrees with our standard orientation on the real number line, i.e., $x$ is moving to the right.
\begin{align*}
\int_\mathcal{C_1} (x+y) ds &= \int_{x=0}^1 (x + (1-x)) \sqrt{2} dx \\
 &= \int_{x=0}^1 \sqrt{2} ~dx \\
&= \sqrt{2}. 
\end{align*}

### And the opposite direction?

We finally arrive at the crux of the matter: if we instead go from $A$ to $B$, why isn't the integral
$$\int_1^0 \sqrt{2}~dx = -\sqrt{2}$$
instead? The answer is subtle, and I'll give a couple different explanations.

1. When $x=1$, $y=0$ and we're at $A$ so $x=1$ is the lower limit. When $x=0$, $y=1$ and we're at $B$ so $x=0$ is the upper limit. **HOWEVER**, this disagrees with the standard orientation of the real number line. If I think of $dx$ as an infinitesimal step in the $+x$-direction, I'll never be able to get from $1$ to $0$ taking $dx$ steps. Instead, I need to take $-dx$ steps. Notice that
   $$\int_1^0 \sqrt{2} (-dx) = \sqrt{2}$$
   as desired. Perhaps think of this as what would happen when setting up a Riemann sum: I would need to have $\Delta x < 0$ to partition from $1$ to $0$.
2. When we set up our integral just using $y=1-x$, we were actually being really lazy about what parametrization we were defining. In particular, this corresponds to the parametrization
   $$\vec{r}(x) = \langle x, 1-x \rangle \quad x \in [0,1].$$
   Notice that we're suddenly using $x$ for a coordinate in $\mathbb{R}^2$ *and* for the parametrization variable in $\vec{r}$. In order to highlight the difference in the double duty that $x$ is being tasked with, I will use $X$ to denote the coordinate in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\chi$ to denote the parametrization variable:
   $$\vec{r}(\chi) = \langle X(\chi), y(\chi) \rangle = \langle \chi, 1- \chi \rangle \quad \chi \in [0,1].$$
   Setting up our integral, we have
   \begin{align*}
   \int_\mathcal{C_1} (X+y) ds &= \int_{[0,1]} (\chi + 1- \chi) \sqrt{2} d \chi \\
    &= \int_{[0,1]} \sqrt{2} d \chi
   \end{align*}
   and we run square into the issue of how to pick our upper and lower bounds. When we parametrized with respect to $\chi$, we implicitly assumed that the orientation of $\chi$ moving from $0$ to $1$ agreed with the orientation of our curve. Perhaps mysterious, but it's *really* important to not confuse the multiple hats that $x$ is wearing.
3. Remember when I wrote that
   $$ds = \sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2} = \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2 } ~dx?$$
   Yeah, that was a lie, just like saying
   $3 =\sqrt{(-3)^2} = -3$
   is a lie. The proper expression would be
   $$ds = \sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2} = \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2 } ~\vert dx\vert.$$
   The question then becomes: *When can I drop the absolute value sign?* The answer to this is precisely when $dx$ is positive, i.e., when we use the positive orientation on the real numbers. If I want to use the opposite orientation on the real number line, then I need to account for this with a negative sign. Thus
   $$\int_{\mathcal{C_1}} (x+y) ds = \int_{[0,1]} \sqrt{2} \vert dx \vert = \int_0^1 \sqrt{2} dx = \int_1^0 \sqrt{2} (-dx).$$
4. Perhaps you've studied the general change of variables formula with the Jacobian determinant? Remember how you need to take the *absolute value* of the determinant of the Jacobian matrix? This accounted for the possibility that your change of coordinates map $G: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ was *orientation-reversing.* It's the exact same story here, except that our change of coordinates map is from a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ to an embedding of a 1-dimensional manifold, which we call a parametrization. The Jacobian matrix will no longer be square, so we can't take the determinant. We can, however, find the singular values...
5. Every single integral you took in Calc I and II was actually a *vector line integral*, for which the orientation mattered. If you analyze an expression like
   $$\int_0^1 x^2 dx,$$
   it usually gets interpreted as "the area between the $x$-axis and $y=x^2$, bounded by $x=0$ and $x=1$." It absolutely does compute that the area is in fact $1/3$, but sweeps a lot of issues under the rug, i.e., what about when our curve goes below the $x$-axis? We usually account for this with some business about "signed area" and such. A more rigorous interpretation would be that we are finding the work done by the vector field $\vec{F}(x) = \langle x^2 \rangle=x^2 dx$ as a particle travels from $x=0$ to $x=1$. The issue that you ran into is that you started with a scalar line integral (orientation of the curve doesn't matter) and converted it into 1-dimensional *vector* line integral, where the orientation matters, by means of a parametrization. This is fine and proper, but we need to ensure that we haven't inadvertently introduced a stray negative sign when doing this translation.